# What is the limiting factor in the iPhone 4S iOS upgrade path?

Tags: ios, iphone

I believe the highest level iOS on an iPhone 4S is 9.3.5.

What is the limiting factor is further upgrades? What service or capability does not exist on the 4s which is needed for higher levels?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This might be opinion based, but let’s see if a good answer is provided other than speculation. Keep in mind, asking why Apple does sometching is generally off topic and gets a question closed. My original edit was to steer this back to something practical

Comment: This is not a question of product positioning, but rather of capability.  If there is some feature that the 4S platform lacks, which is needed for higher level iOS, as an example, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible not to speculate here when you are not an engineer with the needed knowledge at Apple. I'd suggest reading [this](https://www.imore.com/iphone-5s-preview-64-bit-apple-a7-chipset) article from iMore about the iPhones chips and SoC's. You want to search for the A5 (from the 4S) and A6 (from the iPhone 5) and read about the significant increase in performance (which I *think* is the reason for the 4S being obsolete for new iOS's)

Sorry for speculating. I think it's not the right place to discuss this here although I responded...